# Kill program when a certain breakpoint hits

Tags: gdb, breakpoints

I am using gdb to debug my program and I need to try many combinations of inputs. So to make it easier for me, is there a way to kill the debug if a certain breakpoint hits so I can run it again with a different input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to kill the debug if a certain breakpoint hits

You can attach commands to breakpoints. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html). You want something like:

```
break foo        # creates breakpoint 1
commands 1
  call _exit(1)  # causes inferior process to exit. 
end
```